# Building a Lightweight GUI Applet: What's the Most Portable Approach?

Tags: java, user-interface, applet

I am writing a small Applet consisting of a few text fields for use on Linux.  When the user clicks a save button, the values of these fields are saved to a user-specified file.  When the user clicks a load button, a file is read and the text fields are set based on the content of the file.

I written a version using Python Tkinter and am looking at a java SWT applet.

However, both of these require the user to have programs pre-installed (Python+Tkinter and java respectively). I am wondering if it is possible to build a gui applet that could be run on a browser (javascript?) like chrome or firefox, as it is more likely that the user will have these programs pre-installed.  Is this possible, or does the load/save functionality mean some pre-installing cannot be avoided?

In short, if I want to write a GUI applet that reads/writes a couple of text fields to/from files, which approach require the least amount of pre-installation effort from the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is to make an HTML file that can run your Java code. This is a simple task that should be done after you finish your program. In short set up your HTML document and make an Applet tag:

```
<Applet  />
```

then get the directory of your class/Applet:

```
<Applet Codebase="directory" />
```

and lastly set the size of your Applet

```
<Applet Codebase="directory" Width="500" Height="500"/>
```

This link should help:
http://www.echoecho.com/applets01.htm